# Figure how much torque/force to apply for a joint

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

Let's say I have a rod (with mass), that is connected loosely (like a swing) to a stationary axis. I would like to know how much torque I would need to add to cause the rod to point toward a target (see image for clarity) how would I go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a pivoted body the following relationship holds

$$ \tau = I \dot{\omega} + \tau_w $$

where $\tau$ is the torque at the pivot, $I$ is the mass moment of inertia about the pivot (equals $\tfrac{m}{3} \ell^2$ for a rod), $\dot{\omega}$ is the rotational acceleration, and $\tau_w$ is the torque caused by external forces like gravity.

This is something like $\tau_w = \tfrac{\ell}{2} m g \cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle from horizontal the rod makes.

So to make the rod point to a certain point you need to specify how fast you want this to happen and prescribe a motion to the joint from which you calculate torque. For example you need to ramp up the speed to a certain value and then decrease the speed when it reaches the target, making the speed profile a trapezoid, and the acceleration function the derivative of the the speed profile.